# Need to evaluate a double summation which includes an integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, summation, expression-manipulation

Is it possible to evaluate this double summation which includes an integral with Mathematica for some given $r$?

$$\sum_{m=-\infty, m\neq 0}^\infty\sum_{n=-\infty, n\neq 0}^\infty m \int_0^{2 \pi} \log [2r - r\cos \theta + m(\cos \theta-1) + n \sin\theta + m^2 + n^2] d\theta$$

Comment: @MMM what do you mean by MMA? I am a newcomer to Mathematica.

Comment: Where is your try in Mathematica?

Comment: @eurocoder MMA = ***M**athe**M**atic**A***. He is asking you to at least translate your formula into *Mathematica* syntax rather than $\LaTeX$, so people can copy/paste it and play with it. It would also help if you indicated specifically what you have tried and how your attempts have failed.

Comment: Ok I see..I will post the MMA tomorrow when I'm back at my regular computer with Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

Your sum doen't converge at all.
Look how your summands behave if you go to infinity with series.
Here the m-sum, postivie and negative added:

```
    serm1 = 
    Series[m Log[
    2 r - r Cos[θ] + m (Cos[θ] - 1) + 
    n Sin[θ] + m^2 + n^2] - 
    m Log[2 r - r Cos[θ] - m (Cos[θ] - 1) + 
    n Sin[θ] + m^2 + n^2], {m, Infinity, 1}] // Normal

     (*   -2 + 2 Cos[\[Theta]]  *)
```

Every step you add a constant value, therefore your sum must go to infinity.
It's even worse with the n-Sum:

```
    sern1 = 
     Series[m Log[
     2 r - r Cos[θ] + m (Cos[θ] - 1) + 
     n Sin[θ] + m^2 + n^2] + 
     m Log[2 r - r Cos[θ] + m (Cos[θ] - 1) - 
     n Sin[θ] + m^2 + n^2], {n, Infinity, 1}] // Normal

     (*   -4 m Log[1/n]  *)

     Limit[sern1, n -> Infinity]

     (*  m \[Infinity]  *)
```

You can calculate a partial sum numericaly (analytical integration didn't work) to have an impression it goes to infinity:

```
     nint[r_, m_, n_] := 
     NIntegrate[
     Log[2 r - r Cos[θ] + m (Cos[θ] - 1) + 
     n Sin[θ] + m^2 + n^2], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]


  nsum[r_, m0_, n0_] := 
  NSum[m nint[r, m, n] + m nint[r, m, -n], {n, 1, n0}, {m, -m0, m0}]

  Table[nsum[1, k, k], {k, 1, 10}]

   )*  {-6.10232, -34.2553, -88.7863, -169.822, -277.058, -410.236, \
         -569.171, -753.729, -963.815, -1199.36}   *)
```